# Writing a function that will take an AbstractVector as its parameter

Tags: vector, julia

From [Performance Tips](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/performance-tips/#man-performance-abstract-container):

> When working with parameterized types, including arrays, it is best to
> **avoid parameterizing** with abstract types where possible.

Suppose you're writing a function that requires a `Vector`, and with each use of the function, the `Vector` can contain different types.

```
function selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector)
    # Code to sort.
end 

names = String["Sarah","Kathy","Amber"]
unsorted_fibonacci = Int32[8, 1, 34, 21, 3, 5, 0, 13, 2, 1]
    
selection_sort!(names)
selection_sort!(unsorted_fibonacci)
```

When using `selection_sort!()` the first time, the `Vector` contains `String`, the second time `Int32`.

The function knows it's getting an `AbstractVector`, but it doesn't know the type of elements.

1. Will performance be inefficient? Would it be the same as writing `selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{Real})`?

The same section also says:

> If you cannot avoid containers with abstract value types, **it is
> sometimes better to parametrize with Any to avoid runtime type
> checking**.  E.g. IdDict{Any, Any} performs better than IdDict{Type,
> Vector}

2. Would it be better to write the function this way?

```
function selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{Any})
```

If so, why do the [sorting algorithms](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/742b9abb4dd4621b667ec5bb3434b8b3602f96fd/base/sort.jl#L502) just use `AbstractVector`?

```
function sort!(v::AbstractVector, # left out other parameters)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
function selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{T}) where T
    # Code to sort.
end
```

In this way you have an abstract type for the container (and hence any container will get accepted).
Yet those containers con be non-abstract - because they can have a concrete type for their elements  - `T`. As noted by Bogumil - if in the body code you do not need the type `T` you could do `function selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector)` instead.

However, this is just a limit for argument types. Julia would be as happy as to have `function selection_sort!(unsorted_vect)` and the code would be as efficient.

What will really matter are the types of arguments. Consider the following 3 variables:

```
a = Vector{Float64}(rand(10))
b = Vector{Union{Float64,Int}}(rand(10))
c = Vector{Any}(rand(10))
```

`a` is a typed container, `b` is a small-union type container and `c` is an abstract container.  Let us have a look on what is happening with the performance:

```
julia> @btime minimum($a);
  18.530 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime minimum($b);
  28.600 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime minimum($c);
  241.071 ns (9 allocations: 144 bytes)
```

The variable `c` requires value unboxing (due to unknown element type) and hence the performance is degraded by an order of magnitude.

In conclusion, it is the parameter type what actually matters.

Comment: Here is the thing, if it's better to use `where T`, why doesn't Julia's own sort methods use it in the `AbstractVector`?

Comment: Another question (feel free to update your post), isn't saying `where T` no different than saying `selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{Any})`? The [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#where) says so, but I could have a misunderstanding.

Comment: The recommended style is to write `selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector)` as you do not use `T` parameter in the body of your function (unless you do :)). It is equivalent to  `selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{<:Any})` but again the type parameter is not needed here. `selection_sort!(unsorted_vect::AbstractVector{Any})` is incorrect as it would allow only `Any` as element type of a vector. If Julia documentation is not clear for you I explain it in chapter 5.2 of https://www.manning.com/books/julia-for-data-analysis (you should be able to access it for free online).

Comment: @BogumiłKamiński - Feel free to post your own answer, I have followup questions that I don't belive are adequate to ask in the comment section.

Comment: @Mint.Hot.Chocolate - Przemysław knows all what I have written and I see he has updated his answer. If you have additional questions I encourage you to probably ask a new question and either Przemysław or I will answer it (this way we can keep one SO question focused on one issue). Thank you!